# Using powershell to fix a CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV that I am trying to import, and when I attempt the import, numerous entries fail to import because one of the fields is not a valid `http(s)` url. Below is an example

```
username,username2,username3,title,password,note,url,category,otpSecret
foo@gmail.com,,,website1,somepass,,website1.com,,
foo@gmail.com,,,website2,somepass,,https://website2/Login,,
foo@gmail.com,,,website3.com,somepass,,website3.com,,
```

So, as you can see, rows 1,3 fail, and row 2 passes. I need to "patch up" rows 1,3 but I still need all the rows. I'd prefer to not modify in place, but I am not opposed it.

In the end, my data needs to look like this:

```
username,username2,username3,title,password,note,url,category,otpSecret
foo@gmail.com,,,website1,somepass,,https://website1.com,,
foo@gmail.com,,,website2,somepass,,https://website2/Login,,
foo@gmail.com,,,website3.com,somepass,,https://website3.com,,
```

I have have tried to group them by good and bad, that way all I need to do is remap the 'bad' and then save the file back out, but my pwsh just isn't that good.

```
$stuff =Import-Csv -Path ./credentials.csv | Group-Object {$_.url -like 'https*'}
$stuff
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
  121 False                     {@{username=...},}
  284 True                      {@{username=...},}
```

I think the code will look something like this (psuedo code)

```
($stuff | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'False' } | %{... mapping here.. } | Select -First 1).Group + 
($stuff | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'True' } | Select -First 1).Group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided in question the following should help but it's hard to tell if the solution will be robust enough with all the data.

Essentially, it checks if the `.url` value is an absolute `Uri` using the [`IsWellFormedUriString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-7.0), and, if it isn't, it will update that property prepending `https://` to it.

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not [uri]::IsWellFormedUriString($_.url, [UriKind]::Absolute)) {
        $_.url = 'https://' + $_.url
    }

    $_
} | # ... do more stuff in this pipeline
```

Output with this code using the data in question would be:

```
username      username2 username3 title        password note url                    category otpSecret
--------      --------- --------- -----        -------- ---- ---                    -------- ---------
foo@gmail.com                     website1     somepass      https://website1.com
foo@gmail.com                     website2     somepass      https://website2/Login
foo@gmail.com                     website3.com somepass      https://website3.com
```

Comment: Works like a champ!